# Lost one phase in main panel

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

It seems I lost a power from one of phases feeding the panel. The pen tester proofs that. It's interesting if I reset the main switch, the power comes back. If I put any appliance (be it a small light bulb) the power disappears on the same phase until main switch is turned -> off -> on.

I was wondering someone has any theories what could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the service panel cover off? Make sure to shut off every 240V breaker or it can give you false readings.

Comment: I disconnected every 240v breaker and capped the wires inside.

Comment: Have you checked on the supply side of the main breaker or just the output side. Breakers do go bad, I have had quality main breakers loose a leg. Sometimes turning the breaker on and off 10+ times with all the breakers turned off will clean and reseat the hammers in the breaker, if this works be prepared to buy a new breaker and replace or you will have the same problem in the future.

Comment: Nope. Supply side of the main switch is beyond my comfort level as an average Joe homeowner. I am trying to understand science of this phenomena before I pay $000 dollars to electrician for a piece of advice.

Comment: If it's on the supply side of the meter, it's the power company's responsibility and the bill will be $0.00. Calling them is free, I would try it.

Comment: PS&G customer support inflicts emotional toll. They claim the problem is internal (without attempting to get inside to the meter). I scheduled second appointment with them.

Comment: What *did* he do?  On his return appointment if he refuses to fix it, I would say "and take your meter with you, I certainly have no use for it." Of course this will fully remove power from the house, but it sounds like you're there already.  First it will force him to actually open up the meter pan and have a looksy, which may uncover the problem.  Second with the meter gone, it will fully de-energize the main panel so you can work on it without risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely scenario: your main has a connection to the bus inside of the panel that distributes the power to all of the other feeder breakers. That connection is likely bad / corroded / burned, something that is creating high resistance. With no lod, your tick tracer picks up that there is voltage present, but as soon as you apply a load to it, the resistance causes the voltage to drop to effectively zero. Resetting the main breaker wiggles it a little to make just enough of a connection to satisfy that tick tracer, but that's it.

This is your life and safety involved here, the next phase of development of this problem may be a fire. you need to call an electrician.

Comment: I was thinking along the same line. Thanks for the clear explanation.  If it is a corrosion issue, how come it happened in one day? I  would rather  expect this issue to become from incidental to systematic. I will try to deal with the main switch now.

Comment: It could have been incremental, but one day, you hit the threshold. But you're right, that points more toward damage from it being loose and there is a build-up of carbon from arcing that has now reached a point of high resistance.